How do you procede demonstrate that an integral is dervivable.
Let's take
${f} : [a; b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, continuous on$[a; b]$
And
$\Phi : [a; b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $\Phi(x) = \int_{a}^{x}{f}(t)dt$
In the démonstration of the Fundamental Theorem of Integrals we use the dérivabily of $\Phi(x)$, how can we demonstrate that, I thought about the continuity of the sum but I'm not sure. It's my first question on a mathematical forum so excuse me if I made something wrong.

You can just directly calculate the differential quotient via the definition

We have
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\Phi'(x)
& = & \underset{h \to 0}{\operatorname{lim}} \frac{\Phi(x + h) - \Phi(x)}{h} \\
& = & \underset{h \to 0}{\operatorname{lim}} \frac{{\int\limits_a^{x + h} f(t) dt} - {\int\limits_a^x f(t) dt}}{h} \\
& = & \underset{h \to 0}{\operatorname{lim}} \frac{\int\limits_x^{x+h} f(t) dt}{h} \\
& \overset{\text{Mean Value Theorem}}{=}  & \underset{h \to 0}{\operatorname{lim}} \frac{h f(\xi_h)}{h} \\
& = & \underset{h \to 0}{\operatorname{lim}} f(\xi_h) \\
& = & f(x) \\
\end{array}
$$
where the Mean Value Theorem gives us some $\xi_h \in [x, x + h]$ with
$$
\int\limits_x^{x+h} f(t) dt = h f(\xi_h)
$$
Hence, $\Phi' = f$, meaning that $\Phi$ is continuously differentiable.

Yes: all basic facts about integrals are proved from the Mean Value Theorem.

The standard argument here, if we set $\Phi(x) = \int_a^x f(t)dt$, is that
$$
\Phi(x+h)-\Phi(x) = \int_{x}^{x+h} f(t)dt
$$
(by a basic additivity property of the Riemann integral) and hence, to show that $\Phi$ is differentiable at $x$ with derivative $f(x)$, one needs to show that
$$
\frac{1}{h} \int_{x}^{x+h} f(t)dt \to f(x) \text{ as } h \to 0.
$$
Now note that
$$
\begin{split}
\left|f(x)-\frac{1}{h}\int_{x}^{x+h} f(t)dt\right| &= \left|\frac{1}{h}\int_{x}^{x+h}(f(x)-f(t))dt\right|\\
&\leq\frac{1}{|h|}\int_{x}^{x+h}|f(x)-f(t)|dt\\
&\leq \sup_{t\in [x,x+h]}|f(t)-f(x)|
\end{split}
$$
Now if you assume that $f$ is continuous at $x$, then for all $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|f(t)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|t-x|<\delta$, so that $\Phi'(x)=f(x)$ whenever $f$ is continuous at $x$.
(Note that using a Mean Value Theorem for integrals gives a slightly weaker conclusion, since to apply the Mean Value Theorem one needs to assume that $f$ is continuous on the interval $[x,x+h]$.)
